# How to check if a number is a np.float64 or np.float32 or np.float16?

Tags: python, numpy

Other than using a set of or statements

`isinstance( x, np.float64 )` or `isinstance( x, np.float32 )` or `isinstance( np.float16 )`

Is there a cleaner way to check of a variable is a floating type?

Comment: Check out the second answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216088/how-to-check-the-size-of-a-float-in-python

Comment: @MohitBhasi I think that's about the size information rather than the datatype.

Answer (score 65):

You can use `np.floating`:

```
In [11]: isinstance(np.float16(1), np.floating)
Out[11]: True

In [12]: isinstance(np.float32(1), np.floating)
Out[12]: True

In [13]: isinstance(np.float64(1), np.floating)
Out[13]: True
```

Note: non-numpy types return False:

```
In [14]: isinstance(1, np.floating)
Out[14]: False

In [15]: isinstance(1.0, np.floating)
Out[15]: False
```

to include more types, e.g. python floats, you can use a tuple in isinstance:

```
In [16]: isinstance(1.0, (np.floating, float))
Out[16]: True
```

Comment: `np.issubdtype(type(x), np.floating)` can also be useful, it includes `float`.

Comment: Thanks @MarcGlisse, this approach has the advantage of checking for the correct dtype of the whole array. I.e. `np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.floating)`.

Comment: `import numpy as np`
`assert isinstance(x, np.float64)`

Comment: @Marc Glisse Thank you, awesome! And `np.issubdtype(type(x), np.number)` can be used to check for any integers or floats if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 6):

To check numbers in numpy array, it provides 'character code' for the general kind of data.

```py
x = np.array([3.6, 0.3])
if x.dtype.kind == 'f':
    print('x is floating point')
```

See other kinds of data [here in the manual](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.kind.html).

Be careful when using `isinstance` and `is` operator to determine type of numbers.

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1.2, 1.3], dtype=np.float32)

print(isinstance(a.dtype, np.float32))     # False
print(isinstance(type(a[0]), np.float32))  # False
print(a.dtype is np.float32)               # False
print(type(a[0]) is np.dtype(np.float32))  # False

print(isinstance(a[0], np.float32))        # True
print(type(a[0]) is np.float32)            # True
print(a.dtype == np.float32)               # True
```

Comment: Can you clarify your "`isinstance` does not work"? `np.float64` is a class, not a function (`type(np.float64)` is `type`), and `isinstance` works as normal with it.

Comment: @MarkDickinson I added related code.

Comment: This is also useful for pandas `series.dtype` where only dtype (not actual value) is provided.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to a check if a NumPy array is in floating precision whether 16,32 or 64 is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(3).astype(np.float32)
print(issubclass(a.dtype.type,np.floating))

a = np.random.rand(3).astype(np.float64)
print(issubclass(a.dtype.type,np.floating))

a = np.random.rand(3).astype(np.float16)
print(issubclass(a.dtype.type,np.floating))
```

In this case all will be `True`.

The common solution however can be give wrong outputs as shown below,

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(3).astype(np.float32)
print(isinstance(a,np.floating))

a = np.random.rand(3).astype(np.float64)
print(isinstance(a,np.floating))

a = np.random.rand(3).astype(np.float16)
print(isinstance(a,np.floating))
```

In this case all will be `False`

The workaround for above though is

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(3).astype(np.float32)
print(isinstance(a[0],np.floating))

a = np.random.rand(3).astype(np.float64)
print(isinstance(a[0],np.floating))

a = np.random.rand(3).astype(np.float16)
print(isinstance(a[0],np.floating))
```

Now all will be `True`

Comment: I like the `issubclass` approach. The `a[0]` workaround is only effective for 1D data since for higher dimensions it'll return an array.